# How can I display a count of new donors by month?

Tags: civicontribute, civireport, reports, searchkit

This seems a reasonable enough request but I can't put it together.

Here's what I've tried:

- Contribution Summary Report - Does not contain the "Contribution Ordinality" filter (though adding it might be my best option).
- Summary Fields - this is flaky with real-time updates, and scheduled updates lock the database.
- SearchKit - I created a search that grouped contributions by contact ID and gave the minimum ID.  I saved that as a new SearchKit entity (this is new in 5.63).  However, I couldn't join this new entity to other entities, and trying to make an entity from the entity gave me a database error.

Answer (score 2):

I worked it out, you need two SK queries, not three, but you have to group by a partial month.  Screenshots of the two queries are below, along with exports of the queries.
[image]
[image]

```
[
  [
    "SavedSearch",
    "save",
    {
      "records": [
        {
          "name": "First_donations",
          "label": "First donations",
          "form_values": null,
          "mapping_id": null,
          "search_custom_id": null,
          "api_entity": "Contact",
          "api_params": {
            "version": 4,
            "select": [
              "id",
              "display_name",
              "MIN(Contact_Contribution_contact_id_01.id) AS MIN_Contact_Contribution_contact_id_01_id",
              "MIN(Contact_Contribution_contact_id_01.receive_date) AS MIN_Contact_Contribution_contact_id_01_receive_date"
            ],
            "orderBy": [],
            "where": [],
            "groupBy": [
              "id"
            ],
            "join": [
              [
                "Contribution AS Contact_Contribution_contact_id_01",
                "INNER",
                [
                  "id",
                  "=",
                  "Contact_Contribution_contact_id_01.contact_id"
                ]
              ]
            ],
            "having": []
          },
          "expires_date": null,
          "description": "Do not delete - necessary for \"New One-Time Donors by Month\""
        }
      ],
      "match": [
        "name"
      ]
    }
  ],
  [
    "SearchDisplay",
    "save",
    {
      "records": [
        {
          "name": "FirstDonationsDbEntity1",
          "label": "First donations",
          "saved_search_id.name": "First_donations",
          "type": "entity",
          "settings": {
            "sort": [],
            "columns": [
              {
                "type": "field",
                "key": "id",
                "dataType": "Integer",
                "label": "Contact ID",
                "spec": {
                  "name": "id",
                  "data_type": "Integer",
                  "suffixes": null,
                  "options": false,
                  "fk_entity": null,
                  "original_field_name": "id",
                  "original_field_entity": "Contact"
                }
              },
              {
                "type": "field",
                "key": "display_name",
                "dataType": "String",
                "label": "Display Name",
                "spec": {
                  "name": "display_name",
                  "data_type": "String",
                  "suffixes": null,
                  "options": false,
                  "fk_entity": null,
                  "original_field_name": "display_name",
                  "original_field_entity": "Contact"
                }
              },
              {
                "type": "field",
                "key": "MIN_Contact_Contribution_contact_id_01_id",
                "dataType": "Integer",
                "label": "Donation ID",
                "spec": {
                  "name": "MIN_Contact_Contribution_contact_id_01_id",
                  "data_type": "Integer",
                  "suffixes": null,
                  "options": false
                }
              },
              {
                "type": "field",
                "key": "MIN_Contact_Contribution_contact_id_01_receive_date",
                "dataType": "Timestamp",
                "label": "Donation Date",
                "spec": {
                  "name": "MIN_Contact_Contribution_contact_id_01_receive_date",
                  "data_type": "Timestamp",
                  "suffixes": null,
                  "options": false
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "acl_bypass": false
        }
      ],
      "match": [
        "name",
        "saved_search_id"
      ]
    }
  ]
]
```

```
[
  [
    "SavedSearch",
    "save",
    {
      "records": [
        {
          "name": "Partial_Donation_Dates",
          "label": "Partial Donation Dates",
          "form_values": null,
          "mapping_id": null,
          "search_custom_id": null,
          "api_entity": "SK_FirstDonationsDbEntity1",
          "api_params": {
            "version": 4,
            "select": [
              "COUNT(id) AS COUNT_id",
              "EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM MIN_Contact_Contribution_contact_id_01_receive_date) AS EXTRACT_MIN_Contact_Contribution_contact_id_01_receive_date"
            ],
            "orderBy": [],
            "where": [],
            "groupBy": [
              "MIN_Contact_Contribution_contact_id_01_receive_date"
            ],
            "join": [],
            "having": []
          },
          "expires_date": null,
          "description": "Do not delete - necessary for \"New One-Time Donors by Month\""
        }
      ],
      "match": [
        "name"
      ]
    }
  ]
]
```

Comment: This will ONLY show you the count - you can't use this to see totals, for instance.  I've asked Coleman about it, hopefully there's a fix coming soon.